# Search File, Copy File and Rename File in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, ssis, rename

I'm new to SSIS and I have been looking for a way to search,copy and rename a file in SSIS via a sql query.

What I would like to do is:

1. Have a sql query run and pull back filenames from the db
2. SSIS to loop throw a folder for filename
3. Once found copy to archive folder
4. Rename file in achieve folder
5. Move on to the next file in the SQL query

I'm guessing this would be done via a Foreach Loop Container..

Comment: Normally, I would give such questions a -1. But since you are new, I'll overlook that. Please learn the basics of SSIS before you try to do these things. Otherwise, you will be posting questions for each little thing.

Comment: Hint - Use a ADO.net connection to DB. Store recordset in SSIS object variable. Iterate recordset with foreach loop. In for loop, use file task to rename. Do zipping etc.

Comment: point taken Borat ;) and thanks for the wee hit